# Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193 (running CNN webcam on computer)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, syntax-error, kernel, webcam

I just tried running a code on my webcam to be fed into a CNN for predictions in Jupyter Notebook and it killed the kernel when running. I looked into the CMD and it returned this error:

```
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193
```

I have seen similar errors online but I'm not sure how they relate.

I can provide my code if that is useful but I would like to see if there is anything I can do first.

I am using an Acer Nitro 5 laptop if that is relevant (I saw similar errors in relation to Nvidia but I am unsure). I am doing this through Windows 11.

Comment: "I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193"


Saw this above it talking about CUDNN in the CMD

Comment: Comments are only for *requesting* additional information. Please, incorporate all relevant information into the **question post** itself.